# Re-running Docker only until a certain step using caches?

Tags: docker

Is there any option to force Docker to run a build without using caches from that step on?

A particular usecase is something like this:

```
...
ADD some.cfg some.cfg
RUN do something with some.cfg
```

While working on the Dockerfile it is often necessary to adjust configurations and test them.
From the Docker point of view the steps remain unmodified however from my point as a Dockerfile
write I want Docker to run the build using caches until the ADD operation and from that point on
without caches. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Mykola suggests, Docker will take a checksum of the files and should invalidate the cache if the content changes. However, you can always force cache invalidation at a given line in a Dockerfile by setting or changing an environment variable at that point e.g:

```
...
ENV updated-adds-on 14-DEC-14
ADD...
```

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://docs.docker.com/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#build-cache), you don't have to disable cache on the added file change as docker will examine the contents and skip cache on change. Otherwise

> you can use the --no-cache=true option on the docker build command.